# Why do so many identities for the Logarithmic Integral begin with the terms $\log \log n + \gamma +...$?

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory

Several identities for the log integral lead with the terms $\log \log n + \gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

So, for example, there's the well-known

$$\text{li}(n) = \log \log n + \gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{(\log n)^k}{k! k}$$

and

$$\text{li}(n) = \log \log n + \gamma + n^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{x-1}(\log n)^x}{x! 2^{x-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (x-1)/2 \rfloor} \frac{1}{2k+1} $$

or (I don't have good references for the rest of these but they all hold empirically), with $L_n(x)$ the Laguerre polynomials,

$$\text{li}(n) = \log \log n + \gamma + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{L_{-x}(n)-1}{x}$$

and

$$\text{li}(n) = \log \log n + \gamma + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}L_{-x}(n) \text{ at } x=0$$

and

$$\text{li}(n) = \log \log n + \gamma + \lim_{c \rightarrow 1^+} \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log c}\rfloor}\frac{c^j - 1}{j}$$

and

$$\text{li}(n) = \log \log n + \gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1}(\frac{\Gamma(k, -\log n)}{\Gamma(k)}-1) $$

where $\Gamma(k,n)$ is the upper incomplete gamma function.

In other instances, such as

$$\text{li}(n)=\int_0^n\frac{dt}{\log t}$$

and

$$\text{li}(n)=-\pi i - \Gamma(0, -\log n)$$

of course, there is no $\log \log n + \gamma$.

Is there a specific reason why so many of these identities lead with $\log \log n + \gamma$?  I find it very perplexing.

Comment: Well if you know what means the Euler-Mascheroni constant you can realize why it appears so much. The Euler-Mascheroni constant is the difference between two types of integrals, maybe two types of measures, about the same function... with a countable measure (summation over naturals to infinity) and the analytic integral over uncountable differentials. So it fill the gap between logarithm and harmonic series.

Comment: The main thing is that workers in the field use the Cauchy Principal Value as the integral, in fact, diverges at $1.$ For approximations, people often write the integral as beginning at $2.$

Comment: Every identity you have stated involves $\text{li}(x)$, so there really aren't "many" identities involving $\log \log n+\gamma$. What is really happening is that you have just stated several identities for $\text{li}(x)-\log \log x-\gamma$, and it's not really surprising that we can write this in several different ways. The question that seems to be more natural is "why does $\log \log n+\gamma$ appear when looking at $\text{li}(n)$?"

Comment: Eric: If you can answer your reformulation of my question - why does loglogn+γ appear when looking at li(n)? - I'd be just as happy to accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does $\log \log n + \gamma$ appear when looking at $\operatorname{li}(n)$?

For $x > 1$, $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is defined as a principal value integral,

$$\operatorname{li}(x) = \lim_{\varepsilon \searrow 0}\: \Biggl(\int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{dt}{\log t} + \int_{1+\varepsilon}^x \frac{dt}{\log t}\Biggr)\,.$$

The first of the two integrals contributes the $\gamma$. Writing $\delta = -\log (1-\varepsilon)$, the substitution $t = e^{-u}$ yields

\begin{align}
\int_0^{1-\varepsilon} \frac{dt}{\log t}
&= -\int_{\delta}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,du \\
&= \bigl(-e^{-u}\log u\bigr)\biggr\rvert_{\delta}^{\infty}
- \int_{\delta}^{\infty} e^{-u}\log u\,du \\
&= e^{-\delta}\log \delta + \int_0^{\delta} e^{-u}\log u\,du - \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u}\log u\,du \\
&= \log \delta - (1-e^{-\delta})\log\delta + \int_0^{\delta} e^{-u}\log u\,du - \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u}\log u\,du \\
&= \log \delta - \int_0^{\delta} \frac{1-e^{-v}}{v}\,dv - \int_0^{\infty} e^{-u}\log u\,du\\
&= \log \varepsilon + \gamma + O(\varepsilon)\,,
\end{align}
using
$$\gamma = -\Gamma'(1) = -\frac{d}{d\alpha}\biggr\rvert_{\alpha = 1}\int_0^{\infty} u^{\alpha-1}e^{-u}\,du$$
and differentiating under the integral.

The $\log \log x$ term arises naturally in several ways to evaluate the second integral. If we make the substitution $t = e^u$ there, we obtain
$$\int_{1+\varepsilon}^x \frac{dt}{\log t} = \int_{\log (1+\varepsilon)}^{\log x} \frac{e^u}{u}\,du\,,$$
and since the integrand on the right behaves very much like $1/u$ near $0$ it is natural to write it as $\frac{1}{u} + \frac{e^u-1}{u}$ to get one part we can easily explicitly evaluate, and another well-behaved part. This yields
\begin{align}
\int_{1+\varepsilon}^x \frac{dt}{\log t}
&= \int_{\log (1 + \varepsilon)}^{\log x} \frac{du}{u} + \int_{\log (1+\varepsilon)}^{\log x} \frac{e^u-1}{u}\,du \\
&= \log \log x - \log \log (1+\varepsilon) \\
&\qquad + \int_0^{\log x} \frac{e^u-1}{u}\,du - \int_0^{\log (1+\varepsilon)} \frac{e^u-1}{u}\,du \\
&= \log \log x - \log \varepsilon + \int_0^{\log x} \frac{e^u-1}{u}\,du + O(\varepsilon)\,.
\end{align}
Adding both parts and taking the limit thus gives
$$\operatorname{li}(x) = \log \log x + \gamma + \int_0^{\log x} \frac{e^u-1}{u}\,du$$
for $x > 1$. Expanding the last integrand into a power series and integrating term by term yields the first formula.

Comment: Alternatively, one can look at $\operatorname{Ei}(\ln x)$ (where $\operatorname{Ei}$ is the exponential integral) and then ask why $\operatorname{Ei}(u)$ has a $\gamma+\log u$ term